# Multiple lines macros in c++

Tags: c++, oop, visual-c++, macros

I tried to write the macros for the code below but the Test word is underline with red and I do not know if the macros I declared are correct.
 The code is:

```
ABC Test{
int x,y,z;
AAA:
Test() : INIT(x),INIT(y),INIT(z) { }
CREATE(x);
CREATE(y);
CREATE(z);
};
```

I this the ABC word should be an equivalent for "class" and AAA is "public".
The macros I wrote are:

```
#define ABC class name\
int _DATE_
#define AAA public
#define INIT(number)\
{int number = _COUNTER_}
#define ZERO  0
#define CREATE(number) number = ZERO;
```

Comment: Start at reading about the [`/E` option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/e-preprocess-to-stdout?view=vs-2017). Useful know-how when writing preprocessor macros.

Comment: If you're in doubt what your macros do, you might do a preprocessor-only compile. (gcc has an option `-E` for this, other compilers provide a similar option.) That produces the C/C++ code after preprocessing - sometimes very enlighting.

Comment: Andrei I edited my answer, may be that can help you ...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat You're correct. (I was trapped by the short explanation in Google without reading further. When I googled again it asked immediately "Did you mean \_\_DATE__?" My fault.)

Comment: Try never to use macros in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

if m.cc is

```
#define ABC class name\
int _DATE_
#define AAA public
#define INIT(number)\
{int number = _COUNTER_}
#define ZERO  0
#define CREATE(number) number = ZERO;

ABC Test{
int x,y,z;
AAA:
Test() : INIT(x),INIT(y),INIT(z) { }
CREATE(x);
CREATE(y);
CREATE(z);
};
```

then (can use also *gcc* of course) :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ -E m.cc
# 1 "m.cc"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 1 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "m.cc"
# 9 "m.cc"
class nameint _DATE_ Test{
int x,y,z;
public:
Test() : {int x = _COUNTER_},{int y = _COUNTER_},{int z = _COUNTER_} { }
x = 0;;
y = 0;;
z = 0;;
};
```

so indented :

```
class nameint _DATE_ Test{
    int x,y,z;
  public:
    Test() : {int x = _COUNTER_},{int y = _COUNTER_},{int z = _COUNTER_} { }
    x = 0;;
    y = 0;;
    z = 0;;
 };
```

probably not the expected result ;-)

---

Perhaps you wanted something like :

```
#define ABC(name) class name {int _DATE_;
#define AAA public
#define INIT(number)  number(_COUNTER_)
#define ZERO  0
#define CREATE(number) int number = ZERO;

ABC (Test)
CREATE(x)
CREATE(y)
CREATE(z)
AAA:
Test(int _COUNTER_) : INIT(x),INIT(y),INIT(z) { }
};
```

then :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ -E  m.cc
# 1 "m.cc"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 1 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "m.cc"

class Test {int _DATE_;
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
int z = 0;
public:
Test(int _COUNTER_) : x(_COUNTER_),y(_COUNTER_),z(_COUNTER_) { }
};
```

so indented :

```
class Test {
    int _DATE_;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int z = 0;
  public:
    Test(int _COUNTER_) : x(_COUNTER_),y(_COUNTER_),z(_COUNTER_) { }
};
```